# How to search through a list of n-dimen vector to find a vector in that list using R?

Tags: r, vector, arules

I am using Associations Rules to Predict the a next event in a **sequential chain of event**

I got rules using Arules R package As

```
         lhs          rhs   support  confidence lift        itemset
[1]      {11,3,4} => {10} 0.9523810       1.00 1.05       2
[2]      {10,3,4} => {11} 0.9523810       1.00 1.00       2
[3]     {10,11,4} =>  {3} 0.9523810       1.00 1.05       2
[4]     {10,11,3} =>  {4} 0.9523810       1.00 1.05       2
[5]   {11,12,3,4} => {10} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       3
[6]   {10,12,3,4} => {11} 0.8095238       1.00 1.00       3
[7]   {10,11,3,4} => {12} 0.8095238       0.85 1.05       3
[8]  {10,11,12,4} =>  {3} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       3
[9]  {10,11,12,3} =>  {4} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       3
[10]   {11,3,4,8} => {10} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       4
[11]   {10,3,4,8} => {11} 0.8095238       1.00 1.00       4
[12]  {10,11,4,8} =>  {3} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       4
[13]  {10,11,3,8} =>  {4} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       4
[14]  {10,11,3,4} =>  {8} 0.8095238       0.85 1.05       4
[15]  {10,11,3,4} =>  {0} 0.8095238       0.85 1.05       5
[16]   {0,11,3,4} => {10} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       5
[17]   {0,10,3,4} => {11} 0.8095238       1.00 1.00       5
[18]  {0,10,11,4} =>  {3} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       5
[19]  {0,10,11,3} =>  {4} 0.8095238       1.00 1.05       5
[20]  {10,11,3,4} =>  {1} 0.8571429       0.90 1.05       6
```

now I want to take a vector like (1,5,8,9) as input and search it through each of the rules, 
I am not clear what type of data type is rules$lhs[1] , typeof(rules$lhs[1]) gives integer,

It will be great help any one can suggest how to do it in R

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

arules uses the S4 class system. To get the LHS use `lhs(rules)`. The class is `itemMatrix`. You can use `encode` (look at `? encode`) to translate item names into the sparse itemMatrix encoding.

Here is an example for what you want to do:

```
> library(arules)
> data(Groceries)
> rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support = 0.001))
> class(lhs(rules))
[1] "itemMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "arules"

# these are the items I want to match the lhs of the rules with
> lhs_character <- c("rice", "sugar")
> lhs_itemMatrix <- encode(lhs_character, itemLabels = itemLabels(Groceries))

# subset finds all rules with the items in the lhs
> ss <- which(is.subset(lhs_itemMatrix, lhs(rules)))
> inspect(rules[ss])
    lhs             rhs          support     confidence lift     count
[1] {rice,sugar} => {whole milk} 0.001220132 1          3.913649 12
```